# How to disable JavaScript browser API suggestions in Intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

How does one disable web API suggestions in VSCode? Eg, if I type "id" I get a bunch of IndexDB suggestions. I'd like to disable this if possible.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Go to your Settings or press `Command + ,` and search for `intellisense` you will see bunch of autocompletion settings, look for the one that you want to hide, copy/paste into user settings and toggle it to `false`.

Comment: I see 5 options, none of which seem to be related to this issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried `id` in my VSCode but I dont get any such intellisense recommendation, may be some of your extensions/plugins are bringing in additional stuff, next you can try is see if disabling related extension and restarting your IDE resolves it.

Comment: I've disabled every extension that make sense and it's still happening. Are you opening a JavaScript file?

Comment: Yes I was opening javascript file. What kind of file you have? Not a best solution but may be you could give a shot at https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/ which will give you Beta version features and you'll be able to see if its still happening

Comment: I disabled extensions and it still does this for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes VS Code includes DOM completions in javascript by default. To disable this, create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) at the root of your project and set `"lib"` to `"es6"`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": ["es6"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

This tells VS Code's intellsenese to only include the standard es6 library typings when providing intellisense.

You can find more information on support `"lib"` settings [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I added this file in the root of my project and reloaded the window but I'm still seeing those suggestions. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes. In the js file, if you run the `go to project configuration` command, does it open the correct `jsconfig.json` file?

Comment: I do not see a "Go to project configuration command" when typing "CMD + Shift + P". Are you sure that isn't an extension?

Comment: Yes, did you have a js file open?

Comment: I wasn't. Didn't realize that was needed. It is saying it is missing despite it being there. Any idea why it wouldn't be working? If I click "Configure jsconfig.json" it opens the right file

Comment: I moved it to my "src" directory and it worked! Not sure why root didn't work but now I'm not seeing the "id" suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me. I have added the `jsconfig.json` and the `go to project configuration` opens it correctly. But I am still seeing browser suggestions.