# Configure vscode's intellisense JavaScript completion

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is there a way to fine tune intellisense in vscode?

For example, autocomplete on a blank line is producing a ton of options, `Audio`, `CustomEvent`, `DataTransfert`, etc, all of which is not of every day use. Hundreds of unneeded options by the rest of us.

So, is there a way to properly configure which variables is there in the autocomplete or not?

This tool is supposed to speed up development, right, so being fine configurable seems natural.

[image]

The setting `"javascript.nameSuggestions": false` helps a little, but is not a proper details configuration.

Comment: This question may be relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51508907/306149

Comment: @MattBierner Thanks! This jsconfig.json is a good start. Do you have any idea where it is documented in details?

Comment: The jsconfig.json doc is there (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig), but no sign of `compilerOptions.lib`, `compilerOptions.noLib` seems to have the same effect (both are working)